# How to ingnore/exclude specific values in R-Cran, e.g. Zero

Tags: r

I have data, which I want to do a PCA with. In order to do so I want to log the data because the range of my data is very high (from 0 to four digits). (if you have a better method I'd also be interested :)

The data contains zero values, which should of course be excluded from the log. So How do I do this in R-Cran?

What I do is:

```
logmydata<-log(mydata)
```

It logs then also the zero values which returns -inf, which I don't like!

I think this should be very easy, but maybe because it is so basic I couldn’t find it. I'm just a beginner, sorry for that!

All the best!

Lukas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you just want to make the zeros `NA`s?

```
mydata[ mydata == 0] <-NA
```

or remove them from the analysis altogether

```
nozeromydata <- mydata[ mydaya != 0 ]
```

if you don't like either of these suggestions, I say:

```
log( mydata + 1 )
```

Comment: Oh, making them NA is no alternative, because these are real zero values. But the second alternative works like this? I type logmydata<-log(mydata !=0) and then it logs all the variables exept for 0?

Comment: If you retain the zeroes then there is going to be ambiguity in your data: how will you differentiate between those points which were originally zero and those which have become zero after applying log()? remember that log(1) = 0.

Comment: Very very good remark! I see now, that logging the data is not a good way of normalising the data. You have a better one? Nonetheless... it would be nice to know how it's done. mydatalog<-log(mydata[mydata !=0]) turns the table into plain unsorted numbers.

Comment: One oft-used trick is to replace `0` with `1e-16`  which avoids infinities but presumably lets you discriminate zeroes from nonzeroes in your log(data).

Comment: After some time of research... this indeed did the trick! But it wasn't necessary, as FactoMinerR standardizes the data by default by using the standart deviation/mean (something like that).. so sorry for your timewaste :)